# KendoUI Mobile with asp.net mvc

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile

Is it possible to do a KendoUI mobile project, using ASP.net mvc? Watching the introduction on Pluralsight, I'm sort of confused. As an example, KendoUI Mobile uses something like this to navigate:

```
<a href="#someView" data-role="button">Go to some view</button>
```

When rendering views through RenderBody in my main layout, will I have to specify this view as a mobile view, or does the application defined in my main layout pick up on this?

So, I guess my *question* is this; Has anyone got any experience on this combination and, if so, could you provide some resources as to where this combination is being used?

Comment: I would suggest you go with pure HTML files for mobile development as KUI Mobile is a SPA(single page application) framework.. if you really need to use MVC, you can use remote view/External view concept of Kendo UI Mobile to load other views(using ajax). As long as you provide HTML content with a Kendo view in the remote view, it should work. 

Again, you need to take a step back and think if you should really need to use ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Whizkid747. My mobile project is part of a solution that uses asp.net mvc to build a dashboard, so I need to get the same data, based on the same models and controllers. (Unfortunately?) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this on out. Seems to be a few projects out there using this combination. One example is this project: [KendoUI mobile task manager](http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page%3akendo-ui-mobile-task-manager-part-1)

That being said, I'll try to play around and tweak the framework to my needs.

Comment: You can use web api to expose data to ur mobile ui if u r using mvc 4. Thats what i do in my current project

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. I was searching for the same answers, and found this resource very helpful, using MVC4, with detailed explanations:

[Single Page App using MVC and Kendo Mobile](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1308071)

When searching for references and tutorials, what is not immediately clear is that Kendo UI Mobile is a different setup from Kendo UI. As WhizKid points out it is a single page application, and all your data must go through AJAX.

If you have not used them before, you will probably need to learn Kendo's MVVM and datasources. You must decide what sort of interface you will use for data exchange (eg. WebApi, OData) and fix the routing.

The reason I am going this way is because Kendo comes with good looks, and MVC can help me with localization.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: @bluefeet, The question asked for resources, so I provided one, that is actually better than the one in the accepted answer. I don't have enough reputation to add comments, or I would have shoved the link into a comment onto the accepted answer. Can you suggest any other way? thanks.

Comment: The problem is that if that think ever goes down, then this answer is no longer useful.  If you feel that the link answers the question, then you should summarize keys point here and leave the link as a reference.